# bagging logistic regression in r

Tags: r, logistic-regression

R_blogger provides the following code, where my additions are commented out because they don't work; I am seeking a way to save coefficient vectors and p values from the iterated logistic regressions so I can prune variables that consistently don't score well.

```
predictions <- foreach(m=1:iterations,.combine=cbind) %do% {
  training_positions <- sample(nrow(training2), size=floor((nrow(training2)/length_divisor)))
  train_pos<-1:nrow(training2) %in% training_positions
  glm_fit <- glm(default~. ,data=training2[train_pos,],family=binomial(logit), 
                 type=response, control = list(maxit = 25))
  predict(glm_fit,newdata=testing)
  #pvalues <- summary(glm_fit)$coeff[-1,4] < 0.0001
  #coeffs <- summary(glm_fit)$coeff[-1,3] 
  }
probs <- rowMeans(predictions)
```

I want to be able to do retrieve objects for coefficients and p values similar to predictions

Comment: Return everything you are interested in in a `list` and change the `.combine` parameter.

Comment: Why do you want p-values? Usually, one looks at variable importance statistics to determine which variables seem most important in terms of predicting the response. There are canned functions for this already in place in the **caret** package, which I suggest you take a look at; it can work with bagged models such as this...

Comment: @Roland How do I change the combine parameter? Doc on it is sketchy. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NB** This response has been reworked based on the exchange in the comments.

So there are several things going on here.

1. I assumed that the dataset `training` which you provided is supposed to be the same as `training2` in your code. The first column in this dataset is an id, and your code will include that as a parameter in the fit. Is that what you wanted??
2. Your code for extracting a sample of rows is unnecessarily complex. You generate a sample of integers between 1 and `nrow(training2)`, and from that generate a vector of logical with `length=nrow(training2)`. You don't need to do that: just use the vector of integers to index training2. It is *much* faster, especially with such a large dataset.
3. When attempting a fit with such a large number of parameters (>1400), `glm(...)` seems to want an initial estimate of the means. Rather than spending time on that I just restricted the model to the first 9 parameters (columns 2:10).
4. Using `type=predict` in the call to `glm(..)` affects how weights are used. You are not using weights, so this parameter does nothing.
5. However, in the call to `predict(...)` you *do* need to specify `type="predict"`.
6. Using `maxit = 25` generally meant the fits did not converge, so you need to experiment with that.
7. In the small set of iterations I tried, none of the coefficients had `p<0.0001`, so I changed the cutoff to 0.1 for the sake of the example.
8. And finally, using `return(list(...))` as in the code below, plus changing `.combine=cbind` to `.combine=rbind` returns an array of list objects, where each *row* corresponds to an iteration, and column 1 has the vector of predictions for that iteration, column 2 has the vector of p-values for that iteration, and column 3 has the vector of coefficients for that iteration.

Here's the code:

```
library(foreach)
set.seed(1)
training2      <- training
length_divisor <- 1000
iterations     <- 5
predictions <- foreach(m=1:iterations,.combine=rbind) %do% {
  training_positions <- sample(nrow(training2), 
                               size=floor((nrow(training2)/length_divisor)))
#  train_pos<-1:nrow(training2) %in% training_positions
  glm_fit <- glm(default~ . ,
                 data=training2[training_positions,c(2:10,ncol(training2))],
                 family=binomial(logit),
                 control = list(maxit = 25))
  pr <- predict(glm_fit,
                newdata=training2[sample(1:nrow(training2),10),], 
                type="response")
  s <- summary(glm_fit)
  p <- s$coeff[,4]
  c <- s$coeff[,1]
  pvalues <- p[p<0.1]
  coeffs  <- c[p<0.1]
  return(list(pr,pvalues,coeffs))
}
predictions
#          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]     
# result.1 Numeric,10 Numeric,0 Numeric,0
# result.2 Numeric,10 Numeric,0 Numeric,0
# result.3 Numeric,10 Numeric,2 Numeric,2
# result.4 Numeric,10 Numeric,0 Numeric,0
# result.5 Numeric,10 Numeric,0 Numeric,0
```

So in this arrangement, `predictions[,1]` is a list of all the prediction vectors, `prediction[,2]` is a list  of all the p-values<0.1 for each iteration, and `prediction[,3]` is a list of all the coefficients with p-value<0.1 for each iteration.

Comment: won't this just overwrite every time? I think I need some way to make them combine. See comment @Roland above

Comment: Well, since you didn't provide a reproducible example, I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. This code will extract the p-values and coefficients for each fit which have p<0.0001 (in other words, the highly accurate coefficients). To return this, along with the predictions, try: `c(predict(glm_fit,newdata=testing),pvalues, coeffs)` as the last statement in the function block. I can't actually test anything because you provide no data and your code does not run as-is.

Comment: thx, I already tried adding
  list <- c(predict(glm_fit,newdata=testing), (summary(glm_fit)$coeff)[,2],(summary(glm_fit)$coeff)[,4] )
inside the loop and added .multicombine=TRUE in options but list didn't aggregate

Comment: What do you mean by "aggregate"? This code should generate a list (`predications`) of lists, where each element has the predction, p-values, and coefficients of that iteration. There's no "aggregating". You would need to do that later. If this is some kind of effort to figure out which parameters to keep, you should use `stepAIC(...)`.

Comment: Data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/brcwxvs9oodrdtj/training.RData
The original code produces a data frame of nxm, where n is the number of (rows) being predicted, and m=iterations. When I run
with list statement, the resulting list is nx1, so it's not *combining* (aggregate wrong word). You will need to create training and test data sets from the above. Thanks in advance if you fix

Comment: With .multicombine=TRUE I dropped the list notation and simply had the two objects from coeff created in the loop after the predict statement, thinking that maybe they would be combined with the results of the predict statement, but only the predict results were combined in the predictions data frame (actually a matrix).

Comment: If using the data do this:
training$default <- (1*(training$loss > 0))
training$loss <- NULL

Comment: JL - nice work. Coming from SAS, having to deal with lists of uneven length in a matrix sent me to sink (command) and Excel quickly where I can get what I need with one sort and one text to columns after running this. This procedure operationalizes bagging with coefficient pruning in R, a field-tested technique in finance for getting very stable parameter estimates.